# Where I can place GTK+ Themes?

Tags: themes

I've copied all themes to `/usr/share/themes` but in gnome shell tool I see only system themes. I want to change my window background. System Themes suck! What should I do?

Comment: This question seems to be more like a rant than a real question. Voted to close. _Personal opinion. That font makes me want to cry._

Answer (score 1):

You must use GTK3 theme, and copy it to `/usr/share/themes`.
GTK2 themes are not compatible with GTK3 nor with Unity or with Gnome-Shell in 11.10